# Use sprintf to round a matrix while keeping trailing zeros in R

Tags: r, latex

From what I can tell if sprintf is used on a matrix it will convert to a vector and return a vector, in the process, stripping away row and column names. I would like to round a large matrix to one decimal place but keep trailing zeros. Here is a small example of the problem.

```
tbl <- matrix(c(2.4, 3.97, 1.02, 2.3), 2, 2)
colnames(tbl) <- letters[1:2]
rownames(tbl) <- letters[3:4]

tbl_round <- round(tbl, digits = 1)    
tbl_round
#     a   b
# c 2.4 1.0
# d 4.0 2.3
tbl_round[1,2]
# [1] 1

tbl_sprintf <- sprintf("%.1f", round(tbl, 1))
tbl_sprintf
# [1] "2.4" "4.0" "1.0" "2.3"
tbl_sprintf[3]
# [1] "1.0"
```

Is there a way to round a very large table that (a) keeps the trailing zeros and (b) doesn't destroy the structure of the table?

I'm aware I could put the sprintf vector back into a matrix and rename rows and columns but I'm wondering if I'm missing a more straightforward solution.

Comment: The output from `sprintf` is character class. Wouldn't that be a problem?  `tbl[] <- sprintf("%.1f", round(tbl, 1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dim` attribute of your original matrix to specify the `dim` attribute of your output matrix:

```
tbl[] <- `dim<-`(sprintf("%.1f", tbl), dim(tbl))
tbl
#   a     b    
# c "2.4" "1.0"
# d "4.0" "2.3"
```

Note: There's no point in `round`ing your matrix before passing it to `sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks. What does 'dim<-' do? I know what the dim function does, but what is the meaning of quoting it with an assignment arrow?

Comment: @bsbk the `dim<-(x, dims)` function is just a convenient (in this case) way of assigning the dim attribute without creating the object first (as in: `x <- something; dim(x) <- dims`) thus allowing you to write just one line of code instead of two.

Comment: That's helpful. Seems like this construction where you put a function in quotes next to an assignment arrow can be used generally because, for example, 'colnames<-'(tbl, 1:2) reassigns the column names of the table to 1:2. Any chance you can point me to where this is covered in help files?

Comment: @bsbk I can't point you to a specific help file, but it works with basically any assignment function (`names<-`, `[<-`, `attributes<-`, etc.) so anytime you see a function with an assignment method, you can probably do this. It obfuscates your code, but can be convenient in some cases such as this.

Comment: Sounds good. By the way, I think you are missing quotes around the dim<- in your comment above that begins "@bsbk the dim<-(x, dims) function...".

Comment: Yea, that's a Stackoverflow thing...it's hard to show backticks in comments.